# How to retrieve data from a JSON file using Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON file that I parsed using Gson and I want to retrieve a variable named "ModelUrl" inside of it. As it seems, the data is a subdata of another node or data whatever you call and because of it I can not get the values that I want from the variable. I tried using such a function like: System.out.println(jsonObject.get("ModelUrl")), but it only returns null. How can I iterate in all the variables inside and get the variable that I specifically want?

Data is kinda big to put here, but I am gonna put a example to show what I mean by saying "subdata".

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Ukmu9QjFPN3GCnr0Rp3QzHmoxm8XmUs/view?usp=sharing

Here is the data if you want to look.

```json
"CatalogList":{"Items":[{"HasCampaignBanners":false,"ModelId":6280454,"ModelUrl":"/tr-TR/TR/urun/LC-WAIKIKI/kadin/Tunik/6280454/2747034","DefaultOptionImageUrl":"https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/600/-/pim/productimages/20222/6280454/v1/l_20222-w2ic27z8-r3e-78-61-93-174_a.jpg","OptionImageUrlList":["https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/600/-/pim/productimages/20222/6280454/v1/l_20222-w2ic27z8-r3e-78-61-93-174_a.jpg","https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/600/-/pim/productimages/20222/6280454/v1/l_20222-w2ic27z8-r3e-78-61-93-174_a1.jpg","https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/600/-/pim/productimages/20222/6280454/v1/l_20222-w2ic27z8-r3e-78-61-93-174_a2.jpg"]}

//Something like this.
```

And here is the basic script that I wrote for retrieving data.

```java
JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(data);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("ModelUrl"));
```

Comment: Your example JSON doesn't contain a `"ModelUrl"`, so obviously, it cannot be retrieved.

Comment: I put the data as an example, I know it doesn't has ModelUrl in it :).

Comment: The file that I want to search in is big to post, there was a misunderstanding about the example it seems. I just put the example JSON to show what is the data I am trying to search look like.

Comment: It is important that example data you give matches the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well I should put a link then, at least showing the file might help people to understand the question better.

Comment: You don't have to put the entire file, you just need to provide a representative sample that matches your problem description. You say you can't get `"ModelUrl"`, and given your example data, that is not surprising, because it isn't there. If it had contained `"ModelUrl"`, but for example, nested in a nested object, it would result in a different answer, etc.

Comment: Well you are right, but with the example I wanted to show nested datas, not the "ModelUrl" variable. But putting the example of "ModelUrl" data is a much better way to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your JSON data, but based on the problem which you stated giving a general solution:

```
//Assuming JSON data is stored in a String with the name jsonData
//Parse JSON

JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, JsonObject.class);

//Assuming it's inside MenuItemList

JsonArray menuItemList = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Menu").getAsJsonArray("MenuItemList");

// Iterate array

for (JsonElement element : menuItemList) {
    JsonObject menuItem = element.getAsJsonObject();
    String modelUrl = menuItem.get("ModelUrl").getAsString();
    System.out.println(modelUrl);
}
```

It's not a solution to your problem, but it may help you to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got what I need after. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: But since it is close the the code that I use, I am marking your answer.

Comment: Please familarize yourself with the way code formatting works on SO, a block of code should be enclosed in triple backticks, you should not use simple inline code formatting per line for that. I have edited your post to correct this.